# Why 'select * from Employee group by Id' is much faster than directly use the Employee table?

Tags: mysql

In LeetCode Database problems, one called 'Employees Earning More Than Their Managers'. the link is here: https://leetcode.com/problems/employees-earning-more-than-their-managers/description/. The logic is simple:

```
select t.Name
from Employee t
join Employee t1
on t.ManagerId = t1.id
where t.Salary>t1.Salary
```

This costs 350ms. But then I find one fast submission:

```
select a.Name as Employee from
(
    select * from Employee
    group by Id
) a
left join
(
    select * from Employee
    group by Id
) b on a.ManagerId = b.Id
where a.Salary > b.Salary
```

which costs 240ms. The crux may lie in `select * from Employee group by Id`. So I wonder why `select * from table group by id` can make the query faster. Thanks.

Comment: Did you compare the execution plans for the two queries?

Comment: You can explore execution plans with this site: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/623025/1

Comment: Additional reading material: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/bnl-bka-optimization.html

Comment: Thanks for suggestions! In the website the second query is no faster than the first one. I guess the the problem might be in difference between servers. Those suggestions are really helpful, thanks again! (^_^)

Answer (score 0):

On first query you compare

```
on t.gerId = t1.id
```

On second

```
on a.ManagerId = b.Id
```

Also on first is a inner join on second a left join, those queries and results are not the same.

Comment: I am sorry for typing wrongly and I have revised. But the fact is that left join has roughly  time cost(320ms) with inner join. So I think the way of 'join' make little difference.